# Rolling values by group

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

I would like to do some calculations using frollaply()  or rollapplyr() with a conditional factor.

I have the following data

```
df <- tibble(w = c(NA, NA, "c1", NA, NA, "c2", NA, NA, "c3", NA, NA, "c4"), 
             x = 1:12, y = x * 2) %>% 
    as.data.table()
```

Using **data.table** I generate the following result.

```
df[, sumx := frollapply(x, 3, FUN = sum)]
```

| w | x | y | sumx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 | NA |
|  | 2 | 4 | NA |
| c1 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
|  | 4 | 8 | 9 |
|  | 5 | 10 | 12 |
| c2 | 6 | 12 | 15 |
|  | 7 | 14 | 18 |
|  | 8 | 16 | 21 |
| c3 | 9 | 18 | 24 |
|  | 10 | 20 | 27 |
|  | 11 | 22 | 30 |
| c4 | 12 | 24 | 33 |

I like this result. Although I would to do something more complicated.

**First:** I would like let this output more clean, like this:

| w | x | y | sumx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 | NA |
|  | 2 | 4 | NA |
| c1 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
|  | 4 | 8 | NA |
|  | 5 | 10 | NA |
| c2 | 6 | 12 | 15 |
|  | 7 | 14 | NA |
|  | 8 | 16 | NA |
| c3 | 9 | 18 | 24 |
|  | 10 | 20 | NA |
|  | 11 | 22 | NA |
| c4 | 12 | 24 | 33 |

**Second:** I would like create an another variable, for example "sumx2", where the values of the line "c1" is the sum (OBS: not just sum, could be mean or count of a specific value) of all 4 or 5 or n values of variable "x" above (OBS: If not have 4 or 5 or n values above, this absent values has to be understand as NA). The correspondent lines "c2" and "c3" following the same idea. In this way the output expected would be:

| w | x | y | sumx | sumx2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 | NA | NA |
|  | 2 | 4 | NA | NA |
| c1 | 3 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
|  | 4 | 8 | NA | NA |
|  | 5 | 10 | NA | NA |
| c2 | 6 | 12 | 15 | 18 |
|  | 7 | 14 | NA | NA |
|  | 8 | 16 | NA | NA |
| c3 | 9 | 18 | 24 | 30 |
|  | 10 | 20 | NA | NA |
|  | 11 | 22 | NA | NA |
| c4 | 12 | 24 | 33 | 42 |

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain how to calculate `sumx2`? Does `x2` mean the column `y`?  As an example, can you tell me the how to sum and get the last value `42` in `sumx2`? It seems like the sum of `20 + 22` in `y`, is that just a cocoincidence?

Comment: The "sumx2" correspond to sum for 4 "x" values above for the correspondent "w". So the value 6 in cell correspondent to "c1" as the sum of values of cells with values "1", "2" and "3" of variable "x".
Collum/variable "y" just a bad illustrate, its didn't represent/influence anything in other collumns in this case.
The value of "42" in "sumx2" represent the sum of values "12", "11", "10" and "9" of "x" variable.

Comment: Ok, I trying explain with a real example.
Imagine that I sampled organisms in a rock shore each 10 days in a month and I recorded rainfall everyday. So I would this hipothetic table:
```df <- tibble(date = seq(as.Date("2021-3-1"), as.Date("2021-3-30"), by = "days"),
             rainfall = runif(n = 30, min = 0, max = 75), 
             sample_day = c(rep(NA, 9), "c1", rep(NA, 9), "c2", rep(NA, 9), "c3"), 
             N = c(rep(NA, 9), 10, rep(NA, 9), 15, rep(NA, 9), 30))```
Where sample_day is the day in which organisms were sampled and N is number of organisms sampled.

Comment: ...
I would calculate the sum of rainfall 7 days before the "sample_day" that were represented by "c1", "c2" and "c3". But I also calculate the sum of rainfall 15 days before the "sample_day". 
Because this metrics could influence the number of organisms sampled. 
I use, here, the sum as the metric, but could be other metric as number of days with rainfall lower than any specific value or number of days with 0 value in rainfall, or mean, median and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood everything correctly

```r
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(w = c(NA, NA, "c1", NA, NA, "c2", NA, NA, "c3", NA, NA, "c4"), 
             x = 1:12, y = x * 2) 
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

nm_cols <- c("sumX", "sumx2")

df[, (nm_cols) := list(
  ifelse(is.na(w), NA, zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = 3, FUN = function(x) sum(x), partial = T)),
  ifelse(is.na(w), NA, zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = 4, FUN = function(x) sum(x), partial = T))
)]
df
#>        w  x  y sumX sumx2
#>  1: <NA>  1  2   NA    NA
#>  2: <NA>  2  4   NA    NA
#>  3:   c1  3  6    6     6
#>  4: <NA>  4  8   NA    NA
#>  5: <NA>  5 10   NA    NA
#>  6:   c2  6 12   15    18
#>  7: <NA>  7 14   NA    NA
#>  8: <NA>  8 16   NA    NA
#>  9:   c3  9 18   24    30
#> 10: <NA> 10 20   NA    NA
#> 11: <NA> 11 22   NA    NA
#> 12:   c4 12 24   33    42
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank's Yuriy Saraykin. 

You help me to solve the **first** case.

And for the **second** case. 
How can I apply a condition to "x" variable in frollapply() that link to categories in the "w" variable?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(w = c(NA, NA, "c1", NA, NA, "c2", NA, NA, "c3", NA, NA, "c4"), 
             x = 1:12)
dt[,id:=rleidv(x)]
#dt[,sumx := ifelse(is.na(w),NA,frollapply(x,3,sum))]
dt[,sumx := fcase(!is.na(w),frollapply(x,3,sum))]

dt[,sumx2 := fcase(!is.na(w) & id == 3, frollapply(x, n = 3, sum),
                   !is.na(w) & id >= 4, frollapply(x, n = 4, sum))
                         ]
dt[,id:=NULL]
```

Result:

```
dt
       w  x sumx sumx2
 1: <NA>  1   NA    NA
 2: <NA>  2   NA    NA
 3:   c1  3    6     6
 4: <NA>  4   NA    NA
 5: <NA>  5   NA    NA
 6:   c2  6   15    18
 7: <NA>  7   NA    NA
 8: <NA>  8   NA    NA
 9:   c3  9   24    30
10: <NA> 10   NA    NA
11: <NA> 11   NA    NA
12:   c4 12   33    42
```

Comment: Thank's Peace Wang. This is what I looked for! I really appreciate that.
Thanks for spend your time for help me.

Comment: Aha, I am also happy this is  useful for you. If you upvote the answer to encourage those people , I will be more enjoyable the process to help.